# Get the previous value of a field for a specific column

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am keeping track of all changes of the CATEGORY column.
Very simple it is:

```
CUSTOMER_ID, CATEGORY, NAME, MODIFIED

1, A, MYCUSTOMER, 2022-05-01
2, A, MYOTHERCUS, 2022-05-01
1, B, MYCUSTOMER, 2022-05-02
```

etc

I want to get the following:

```
CUSTOMER_ID, CATEGORY, NAME, MODIFIED, PREVCAT

1, A, MYCUSTOMER, 2022-05-01, null
2, A, MYOTHERCUS, 2022-05-01, null
1, B, MYCUSTOMER, 2022-05-02, A
```

My dataset has a lot more columns, customers and data, but I am stuck with partitioning and lags...

Answer (score 1):

Use below

```
select *, 
  lag(CATEGORY) over(partition by CUSTOMER_ID order by MODIFIED) PREVCAT
from your_table
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: Ah! That does the trick, almost. But 'MODIFIED' can be caused by modification of another column, so CATEGORY is the same (it will show PREVCAT and CATEGORY as the same)